# How to stop resize event from multiplying inside function whenever window is resized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

So whenever I resize my window, This function will be created everytime:

**$('.cookie_box .accept').click(function(){**

So I must somehow define resize? and use it and how would that look like?

```
   $(window).on('load resize',function() {
      $('.cookie_box .accept').click(function(){
        //whatever code
      });
   });
```

Comment: I can't understand what you want. what do you mean by multiplying inside function ?

Comment: So there are not downsides using resize like this having another function in it?

Comment: you can use resize event, but you should run your code inside setTimeout() if the code takes long to execute. because resize event fires up to several hundred times per second and it can become expensive for performance 
A guide on this on css-tricks.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/done-resizing-event/

Comment: other than that you can use any function in your resize event

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
$(window).on('load resize',function() {
  $('.cookie_box .accept').click(function(){
    //whatever code
  });
```

});

means: create a click event handler for each window resize or at window load. It's enough to create only one click event handler. In order to achieve this result you can use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead of [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

An alternative way can be based on:
[.trigger( eventType [, extraParameters ] )](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/#trigger-eventType-extraParameters)

Demo:

```js
$('.cookie_box .accept').click(function(e, triggeredFromLoadResize){
    if (triggeredFromLoadResize === undefined) {
        console.log('Click event coming from: window load resize')
    } else {
        console.log('Normal click');
    }
    //whatever code
});
$(window).on('load resize',function() {
    $('.cookie_box .accept').trigger('click', [ "Custom_Event" ])
});

$('.cookie_box .accept').trigger('click');


//
//  your click handler
//
$(window).on('load resize',function() {
      $('.cookie_box .accept').click(function(){
        console.log('Your click handler');
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="cookie_box">
    <button type="button" class="accept">accept</button>
</div>
```